# Unable to connect to the SYBASE Database in Docker when triggered through FASTAPI

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn, sybase-asa

I am unable to connect to my database inside Docker when I try to trigger an SQL query through an API call. When I do it without Docker, it works.

Details:

When I start the uvicorn server directly with the following command:

```
uvicorn api:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5001 --reload
```

My uvicorn server starts, and is accessible at `http://localhost:5001/`. It has an endpoint `fetch_data`, which when called, executes an SQL select query and the endpoint returns the data as a JSON -> **this works fine**

Now, I run a docker container, which has a kafka service and the same uvicorn server running simultaneously. The docker commands are as follows:

```
docker build . -t container_name -f docker/Dockerfile
docker run -p 5001:5001 container_name
```

(I map port 5001 to access the API externally through the browser at localhost)

Both the kafka messages and the API trigger some SQL query. The SQL query works when triggered via kafka message within docker (it returns data, which means that the app is able to connect to the database within the docker container), but when triggered through the API, it is not able to connect to the database -> **this doesn't work**

In the latter case, I start the uvicorn server directly in python like this (if that makes a difference at all):

```
uvicorn.run(app=app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

I checked through the logs and it seems this line gets stuck indefinitely (it doesn't give any error):

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_url, user, password)
```

I can provide additional information if required, but can anyone provide me a clue as to why my API, when triggered within the docker container, might not be able to interact with the database when the connection is working when triggered through a kafka message?

The swagger page of the API is accessible at `http://localhost:5001/`, and it shows all the endpoints, so I can assure that the API is working fine when I start the uvicorn server within Docker.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple issues

1. Make sure you are providing you DB credentials to the Docker container.
2. Check if you have set the correct Docker network configuration so it can connect to the DB in the network.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the db connection works fine when triggered through a kafka message (in docker), and it works fine on uvicorn when I use it outside docker. This means the credentials are correct and there are likely no issues with the Docker network configuration since it is able to read data from within the container. It just doesn't work when I trigger it through an API call within Docker.

Comment: How are you establishing the database connection in your FastAPI application, and which database drivers are you using for this purpose ?

Comment: I am using JDBC to connect it to the db:

`connection_url = f'jdbc:sybase:Tds:{server}:{port}/{db}'`
`connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_url, user, password)`

This seems to be working when I trigger it via API (ONLY outside the docker container) and Kafka (inside and outside the docker container)

Comment: Is your database located within the same network as your application?

Comment: No. I am connected to the VPN to access the network where the db exists.